# "Only" vs "but only"

Tags: word-usage

Do they mean the same when used in a sentence?

Example:

> A scream would occasionally escape from her, **only** to be absorbed by
>   the dark metallic walls.
>
> A scream would occasionally escape from her, **but only** to be absorbed by
>   the dark metallic walls.

Do both sentences mean the same? If not, what would be the difference?

Comment: The "but" sounds awkward in this sentence.  The first sentence sounds natural.

Comment: Isn't this more proof-reading?

Comment: @Barrie England Sorry, so this should go to writers.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Let's see what others think.

Comment: I agree with @BarrieEngland. I've commented previously that *a lot* of your questions would be better on [Writers.se]. OTOH, I don't necessarily agree with Lumberjack: I think there may be a subtle difference between the two and that the choice may depend on what comes before and/or after this sentence. That is precisely why this and a lot of your other questions may be better on Writers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for writing advice and would be better asked on [writers.se].


Comment: The question asks for a general answer but gives only one special context. In general, _only_ and _but only_ are not substitutable. *They but only work that way occasionally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a special case of *but*, *only* or *but only*. The words *but* and *only* mean just the same here as elsewhere in an English sentence.

> **1** used to introduce a phrase or clause contrasting with what has already been mentioned: *he stumbled but didn’t fall*
>   **2** [with negative or in questions] used to indicate the impossibility of anything other than what is being stated: *one cannot but sympathize*

Let there be no confusion here with the secondary definition of *but* that is not relevant here (used to indicate the impossibility of anything other than what is being stated: *one cannot but sympathize*) -- use the primary: (used to introduce a phrase or clause contrasting with what has already been mentioned: *he stumbled but didn’t fall*)

The sentences do **not** mean the same thing.